# youtube-dl: zsh: no matches found:

Tags: youtube-dl

From Catalina OS X:

```
youtube-dl --version
```

> 2020.09.06

```
youtube-dl  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qohQD51F5bM
```

> zsh: no matches found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qohQD51F5bM

- I have successfully used YouTube-dl on said OS X machine.
- The URL is good

Questions

1. What exactly is the problem?
2. How to overcome said problem?  Thank you.

Update

Enclosing the [URL in single quotes](http://zsh:%20no%20matches%20found:) overcame the problem.  What exactly is it about the URL that requires the quote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Always use either single `'text'` or (preferably) double `"text"` quotes when passing links, email and passwords. Different OS handle input differently.

I believe in your case (very rarely use MacOS) the `?` is triggering something.
You could simply try to remove the `?` from the url and see if it takes the input - obviously youtube-dl will fail because of invalid url.
But that way you can check if the problem is related to the `?`.

Answer (score 4):

Put a backslash `\` in front of the `?`.

Comment: A comment as to why would serve the greater interest